# Echo comma separated values in PHP

Tags: php

I have a invoice table in which three columns have comma-separated values. Now I want to show a report in details for each invoice.

For example,

```
Invoice_id=10
product=1,5,55
category=2,44,25
QTY= 55,2,10
```

So for the above invoice I want to show each product name and category with qty.

Comment: Have you tried something? How do you get the data, with which code?

Comment: Why you use comma separated lists than arrays?

Comment: Database normalization

Comment: youve got to give more details, how is the invoice table stored? Arrays? html table?

Comment: don't store comma seperated values.... it will be a headache when you will need to update just one entry.

Comment: what are these `1,5,55`, `2,44,25`?

Comment: @Prat - this is a searchable issue. Even the simplest search in 2 mins will return an answer/blog post/whatever to help you. It would probs take you less time to search than ask this question. Just trying to help you for future issues.

Answer (score 0):

If they are in the right order and have a consistent correlation, you can do that.

For example, you can explode by ',' the fields and create the output in a for loop like this:

```
//you have to retrieve the data from database, the fields are strings
$product= "1,5,55"
$category= "2,44,25"
$QTY= "55,2,10"
//for each invoice:
$products = explode(',',$product);
$categories = explode(',',$category);
$QTYs = explode(',',$QTY);
for ($i = 0; $i < count($products); $i++){
    echo "Product: " . $products[$i] . ", Category: " . $categories[$i] . ", Quantity: " . $QTYs[$i] . ".<br>"; 
}
```

hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach(explode(' ', 'Invoice_id=10 product=1,5,55 category=2,44,25 QTY=55,2,10') as $key => $value)
        {
            $temp[] = explode('=', $value);
        }

        foreach($temp as $key => $value)
        {
            $final[$value[0]] = explode(',', $value[1]);
        }

        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($final);
```

output:

```
Array
(
[Invoice_id] => Array
    (
        [0] => 10
    )

[product] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1
        [1] => 5
        [2] => 55
    )

[category] => Array
    (
        [0] => 2
        [1] => 44
        [2] => 25
    )

[QTY] => Array
    (
        [0] => 55
        [1] => 2
        [2] => 10
    )

)
```